# How to avoid Outlook Security Alert

Tags: c++, visual-studio, outlook

So I'm interning at a company and essentially self teaching myself C++ to get a head start on classes this fall.
The problem I have that I cannot find a solution for, is how to send an email without user interaction and avoid the security prompts by outlook.

I have tried different ways to send the email like with simplemapi, cmd, vb, cdo, etc but nothing I do seems to get rid of that 'please wait 5 seconds because someones trying to send an email' prompt, and I can't have that.
I also can't install any third party software because I need this program to work on all the company computers.

I'm about to try with System.Net.Mail.MailMessage and see if I can figure that out.

End goal is that they click a button, and an email sends without their knowledge, with no security prompts. If it needs authentication to execute without the prompt I can implement that too. I'm using winapi on 64 bit systems, and have the exe run from sharepoint by pulling from a network drive if that matters. And please don't be closeminded about using MS office, I'll do anything to make it do what I want it to

In the meantime, if I could get a code sample or a link in the right direction (NOT MSDN FFS) that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe there is a setting in the outlook trust center to set for this.  Typically it will not warn as long as you have up to date AV installed.

Comment: I know of this, only problem is I'm at a financial firm and security is tight. Even with up-to-date AV it prompts me unless I completely disable all outlook security, and unfortunately I obviously can't have that, and I'd have to manually set it on 100+ company computers (as far as I know, I'm the one asking questions)
If I'm wrong let me know, or if you have another possible solution please let me know :) like if i could whitelist my exe

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for a list of your options.

Note that `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` will only work against an SMTP server, so it really has nothing to do with Outlook.

Comment: Super Thanks, I've been using that page for the past couple days to problem solve. Instead of SimpleMAPI, I ended up using system("mailto:*******") and keybd_event to send the email. I know it's terrible practice but I couldn't figure it out. I plan to learn extended mapi to accomplish this, but I couldn't find a good learning source, or I just don't know enough yet. I saw you created Redemption, is there a way to implement that without installing it on all company computers? Like I said this all will run from a network drive. I now get to deal with OL scripting after I get this to create/send

Comment: You can use RedempitonLoader - it loads the library without having to install it using regsvr32.exe.http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/security.htm#redemptionloader